# How to best group RadioButtons VBA Excel

Tags: excel, vba, radio-button, grouping

I thought I could group radio buttons by setting the LinkedCell property differently for those I wanted grouped together, however, in my code all of the buttons end up going to the same LinkedCell.  I need to group RadioButtons dynamically because the numbers of buttons in the groups vary.  I am working on an exam program and need to group RadioButtons for each question together, what would be the easiest way to accomplish this?

-next day
I discovered that I was not incrementing the name of the RadioButtons so every button had the same name.  I also made the buttons smaller so that they did not overlap and I got everything to work when I manually placed GroupBoxes, now I have to add them from VBA and cross my fingers.

```
For c = 1 To ExamData(i, 7)
    ws.Range("C3").Offset(rOff + z, cOff).Value = ExamData(i, a)    'write answer
    rbCapt = CaptSelect(c)                                    'Set choice letter as caption
    Set t = ws.Cells(rOff + v, 2)
    Set rb = ws.OptionButtons.Add(t.Left + 20, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)
    With rb
        .caption = rbCapt
        .Name = "Btn" & Trim(Str(b))
        .LinkedCell = "A" + Trim(Str(myRow)) '<- When myRow changes all Buttons change
    End With
```

Comment: To group Option Buttons,  add each set to their own Frame

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545772/how-to-add-option-buttons-to-group-in-excel-2010-sheet-using-vba

Answer (score 0):

Well I worked through at, Adding GroupBoxes worked.  Here is the final code:

```
For i = 1 To UBound(ExamData)
'write question number
    ws.Range("B3").Offset(rOff, cOff).Value = Trim(Str(i)) + "."
    myRow = ws.Range("B3").Offset(rOff, cOff - 1).Row                   'row number of question
'write question
    ws.Range("C3").Offset(rOff, cOff).Value = ExamData(i, 1)
'write answers & Radio Buttons
    For c = 1 To ExamData(i, 7)
        ws.Range("C3").Offset(rOff + z, cOff).Value = ExamData(i, a)    'write answer
        rbCapt = CaptSelect(c)                                          'Get choice letter for radio button
        Set t = ws.Cells(rOff + v, 2)
        Set rb = ws.OptionButtons.Add(t.Left + 11, t.Top + 12, t.Width - 22, t.Height - 20)
        With rb
            .caption = rbCapt
            .Name = "Btn" & Trim(Str(i)) & "-" & Trim(Str(b))
            .LinkedCell = "D" + Trim(Str(myRow))
        End With
        v = v + 1
        a = a + 1
        b = b + 1
        z = z + 1
    Next c
'add GroupBox
    pp = (myRow + 1 + ExamData(i, 7) - 1)
    gbRange = "B" + Trim(Str(myRow + 1)) + ":B" + Trim(Str(pp))
    Set vvv = ws.Range(gbRange)
    Set gb = ws.GroupBoxes.Add(vvv.Left, vvv.Top, vvv.Width, vvv.Height)
    With gb
        .caption = ""
        .Name = "gb" + Trim(Str(i))
    End With
    rOff = rOff + (ExamData(i, 7) + 2)
    v = 4
    z = 1
    a = 2
Next i
```